# json_encode() returns "null" to entries with accents (special characters) but only when they are added manually in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

If I insert an entry with fields that contains special characters, using the phpmyadmin page, the function below will return 'null' to the fields that has special characters, while the fields that does not have special characters are displayed properly.

If I insert an entry using my wepage (jQuery DataTables), with a field that has the same special characters, it will display it properly, with no problems.

Why does only the manually insert is bugging the data displaying?
My DB collate is UTF8, I've set the HTML and PHP charset to utf-8, tried to use utf8_encode(), but none of this seems to work.

Here's my PHP code and usage:

```
    $connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect('localhost',  '',  '')) or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
    ((bool)mysqli_query( $connection, "USE ")) or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));

    $aFieldType = array('tema', 'vinculo', 'empresa', 'subcontratada', 'gerencia', 'areasolicitante', 'cc');
    $stack=array();
    foreach ($aFieldType as $type)
    {
        $sql="SELECT {$type} FROM treinamentos ORDER BY {$type} ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $stack[$type][] = array($row[$type],$row[$type]);
        }
    }
?>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            aDataInitial = '<?php  echo json_encode($stack);?>';
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a data to table via the phpMyAdmin and then see using the console client what was really inserted into the DB. Probably you have a misconfiguration of charsets in the phpMyAdmin UI.

After all, you clearly stated that you do have a UTF-8 set up in you DB, website, and the UI in your own webapp inserts data correctly. So, the only thing you did not checked is the phpMyAdmin. I would try to insert your special string using the mysql console client, too. And of course, check the data being inserted in the client which set to UTF-8 output, too.

Comment: Is there any way to set the charset when I'm making an insertion by phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: In short: I don't know. I would first look in what encoding my browser even watches the phpMyAdmin UI. Second, I would check the parameters for connection to the MySQL server somewhere in the phpMyAdmin settings. And of course you should have a `default charset` set to utf8 everywhere in your DB in first place. There's not the single place for this setting, check the official documentation for MySQL.